# Why is sscanf acting this way?

Tags: c, scanf

I thought that I understood C but i am having a hard time just writing a simple addition code for practice. When I run this code, int a is 0 every time. However, int b works fine. The idea here is that the input to the program is 8 + 9. Why does sscanf not recognize variable a?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int plus(int a, int b){
    return (a + b);
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    char input[100], op;

    printf("...I am ZOLO...\n");
    printf("...The most vercatile calculator known to man...\n");
    printf("...Please enter your query:");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    sscanf(input, "%d %s %d", &a, &op, &b);

    printf("%d + %d = %d...", a, b, plus(a, b)); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `%s` is a string, which you're writing to `op` which is a `char`.  Use `%c` for scanning a char.

Comment: Works fine for me, anyway. What exactly are you using as input?

Comment: @Rubens that it works fines is undefined behavior. He's scanning a null-terminated string into a single char variable by-address. Unless the string is empty (which it cannot be ttbomk) the minimum storage is two chars (one for a char, one for the terminator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonathon Reinhart has the correct answer.  In this case, it's not just the undefined behavior problem, it's the fact that the compiler managed to allocate `op` just before `a` (in internal memory order) and your machine uses little-endian byte order so that the `'\0'` character stored after `op` wipes out the value that was previously stored to `a`.

Comment: Gracias, also thanks for catching my typo @Aniket. I meant versatile.